# String fails to return true when compared to itself.

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web application that is using [ListJs](http://listjs.com/) for sorting and filtering. In one piece of my code I have this function:

```
var filterOptions = { valueNames: ['department'] };

var employeeFilterList = new List('employees', filterOptions);

$('#filter-engineering').click(function() {
  employeeFilterList.filter(function(item) {
    console.log(item.values());
    if (item.values().department === "Engineering") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Essentially, what this is doing is on the web app is using list.js's sorting feature on a directory of employees to return only those in Engineering. Now here is the real problem, by all means this code should work except for this problem.

The `console.log` in the function returns values of each item showed below:

[image]

As you can see, this object's department value is `'          Engineering           '` with some weird encoding in there. By running my code and refreshing the page, I see that `item.values().department === "Engineering"` is always false because of the spacing issue. What could possibly cause something like this and how can I get around it? Is there a way I can chomp the extra spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `trim()` to remove unnecessary white space instead of `if (item.values().department === "Engineering") {` use `if (item.values().department.trim() === "Engineering") {`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using trim? it would be like this:

```
var filterOptions = { valueNames: ['department'] };

var employeeFilterList = new List('employees', filterOptions);

$('#filter-engineering').click(function() {
  employeeFilterList.filter(function(item) {
    console.log(item.values());
    var sanitized = $.trim(item.values().department)
    if (sanitized === "Engineering") {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```